# Image component uri Cross origin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-360

I want to show a photo from an external url:

```
<Image
  style={styles /* Some React Native styling */}
  source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
 />
```

But I get the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load ...

Comment: what does your `Image` component look like?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald It is native react-vr Image component, and the above code is the example of react-vr documentation. but It doesn't work

Comment: apologies, just noticed that. Try replacing `http` with `https` in the url

Comment: I guess a normal `<img src='https://...' />` won't do, right?

Comment: @lumio It's not JSX. It's react-vr!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the dimensions of your image:

```
<Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
   style={{width: 1, height: 1}} />
```

This is referenced in the documentation:

https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/images.html

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#network-images